# What is the difference between HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert and HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I'm working on an ASP.NET web application and I want to implement caching, so I want to know the difference between `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert` and `HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add` and which one is better?

Comment: "Insert" sounds nicer to me and there is no 'd' in it, so it is clearly better :-P

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The main difference between the two is that if an object with the same name already exists in the cache, the `Insert` method call on your instance of `Cache` will replace the object, whereas the `Add` method call will fail (taken from the [Remarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add.aspx) paragraph of methods Add and Insert on their respective MSDN reference page):

**Add**

> Calls to this method will fail if an item with the same key parameter
>   is already stored in the Cache. To overwrite an existing Cache item
>   using the same key parameter, use the Insert method.

**Insert**

> This method will overwrite an existing cache item whose key matches
>   the key parameter.

The other main difference is also that with the `Add` method some parameters are mandatory, whereas with `Insert` , various overloaded methods are available, and some parameters will be set to default values like the absolute or sliding expirations.

You can see that there is no difference between the Add and the [Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx) method with the exact same parameters except that Insert will not fail (i.e. do nothing) if an object with the same name is in the cache.

Comment: Please see my "answer" below regarding what I found out by actually writing code and trying to make Add fail (it did not).

Comment: Actually, please see the comment by Mark Sowul on my Answer below! :-)  "Fail" is not the same as "throw exception".  I knew that in the deep dark recesses of my mind but it certainly did not come to the forefront when reading the MSDN pages.  I think the documentation could have been made clearer.

Answer (score 9):

**[EDIT] 2015-10-29**
See the comment by Mark Sowul below.  UGH!
**[/EDIT]**

I just posted my comments below at the link (Remarks) that Jalayn provided.  Anyone here care to comment?  Anyone counting on getting an error thrown, please see my last paragraph below and shame on you! :)

Being the obstinate type, I thought I'd give this a try.  I wrote some code that looks something like this.

```
var myObject = new MyObjectType() { prop1 = "string 1", prop2 = 1 };
var cacheKey = "mycachekey";
var cTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(11);
var cExp = System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration;
var cPri = System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Normal;

HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey, myObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);
myObject.prop1 = "string 2"; myObject.prop2 = 2;
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey, myObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);
myObject.prop1 = "string 3"; myObject.prop2 = 3;
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, myObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);
myObject.prop1 = "string 4"; myObject.prop2 = 4;
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, myObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);
myObject.prop1 = "string 5"; myObject.prop2 = 5;
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey, myObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);
myObject.prop1 = "string 6"; myObject.prop2 = 6;
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, myObject, null, cTime, cExp, cPri, null);

var foo = (MyObjectType)HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
```

Guess what.  It ran fine.  I even put a break point before and after this code block and executed HttpContext.Current.Cache (in the Immediate window of VS) at each point and verified that only one item was in fact added to the cache.  And foo.prop1 = "string 6".

Anyone from Microsoft care to explain why this did NOT throw an exception?  Although it is poor practice (and our application does not do it) someone may be counting on getting an error thrown and their application may not behave as expected because the CLR does not throw an error even though your documentation says it will.

Comment: The documentation does not say it will throw an exception, only that it will "fail" -- if you look at the "exceptions" list there is no situation for "the item already exists in the cache" (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add(v=vs.71).aspx).  Additionally this says explicitly that it will not raise an exception: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I stand (or rather "sit") corrected.  Wow, though.  Talk about clear as mud.  I am not the only person to make this mistake.  I think they could have made the text `the method will not replace the item and will not raise an exception` slightly more prominent.

Comment: Yeah, definitely not the clearest API.  I think they learned their lesson the second time around, with `MemoryCache`: only one version of Add, and it returns true/false based on whether the item was in the cache: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138343(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 5):

It is always misunderstood that Cache.Add will throw an error if it tries add an item with same parameter. It does not throw any error/exception or rather it will not update and does not throw any error. Check the msdn article below where it says

> #### Cache.Add
>
> Add method returns the object you added to the cache. Additionally, if
>   you use the Add method and an item with the same name already exists
>   in the cache, the method will not replace the item and will not raise
>   an exception.
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx
>
> #### Cache.Insert
>
> If you use the Insert method to add an item to the cache and an item
>   with the same name already exists, the existing item in the cache is
>   replaced

Another difference is Cache.Insert has 5 overloads and Add has only one. And Add method returns the object that was in the cache under that key (null if a new item, otherwise the item currently in the cache), whereas Insert returns nothing.

Add method's [remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.add(v=vs.100).aspx) says fails to update. I guess it is a typo in add page. I think what they meant to say is "Calls to this method will fail **to update** if an item with the same key parameter is already stored in the Cache"

you can try run this code and see yourself whether you get any error/exception.

```
// returns null
Cache.Add("Key1", "Value 1", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);

// returns "Value 1"
Cache.Add("Key1", "Value 2", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
```

Comment: Followed your link.  The word "Add" is a link to same page as the "Remarks" link in Jalayn's answer.  Go to the bottom of that page and you will see the following:
Calls to this method will fail if an item with the same key parameter is already stored in the Cache

Comment: @Andrew Steitz not the same page. 

you can try run this code and see yourself whether you get any error/exception.   

`Cache.Add("Key1", "Value 1", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);`

`Cache.Add("Key1", "Value 2", null, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);`   

I guess it is a typo in add page. I think what they meant to say is "Calls to this method will fail **to update** if an item with the same key parameter is already stored in the Cache"

Comment: Follow YOUR link.  In second paragraph, second sentence, after semi-colon, following text "however, Add".  The word "Add" is a link.  Follow that link.  Takes you to same page as "Remark" link in Jalayn's answer except for the CLR version, 4.0 vs 4.5, but CONTENT is same.  Scroll down to the "Remarks" section.  "Calls to this method will fail if an item with the same key parameter is already stored in the **Cache**"  Most people would interpret "will fail" as an exception but it does not throw an exception, it fails "silently".  They need to clarify.

Comment: Your test does not prove that it replaces the value with a new one: you are changing the item itself; even if you remove all the other calls to `Add`, the item in the cache will still have "string 6" and 6.  If you create a new MyObjectType each time (with the different prop values) rather than changing the existing item, this will be clear.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer, oh the shame!  I was corrected (correctly) by a "novice" programmer and did not even realize that I was wrong!  LOL

Comment: @AndrewSteitz Its alright. :) It part and parcel of learning ;)

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer I know.  That was tongue-in-cheek.  I was poking fun at myself.